# Language for Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines

Maybe someone can shine some light on this problem:

When given the Language L which is defined as:

L := {w ϵ {a,b}* : w=(aba | ba | (ba | w')), with w' ϵ L}

What kind of word can this Language create? Especially if looking at w'.

Does the w' mean that it can be replaced with aba or ba or can it only be replaced with the ba's that are inside of the (ba | w') part?

Smallest words are obviously aba and ba but once I get to the w' part, I am not sure what it can do there.

To be clear, my first intuition would be that the w' can recursively write/read ba's and aba's BUT apparently (when going by a GIVEN solution) it should only allow babababa and so on... Why not abaaba...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: @Progman: Could you clarify what is off-topic about this question? That might help the OP understand how pick a suitable site. Obviously, this question is about a specific programming problem and answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The production

> w=(aba | ba | (ba | w'))

can be expanded to the following choices:

- w = aba
- w = ba
- w = w' (which is again a word from the language)

With these production rules, there can be no infinite recursion.

If there were no pipe symbol between `ba` and `w'`, then you could build infinitely long chains of repeated `ba`. Note, though, that even then, such a long word could never start with an `a`, as the production that creates `aba` does not allow for any repetition afterward.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a quick reply. So what if the w' calls another w' and that one calls another w' and then they each get replaced with a word from L? Or is that not how w' works here?

Comment: @SilverMs: Well, if I interpret that syntax correctly, w' just gets replaced with another w'. You still have just that one w'. There is no production that combines w' with anything else. For instance, if you had something like `w = "ba" | "ba" w'`, you could use the second production multiple times to form a longer chain. But that is not possible here, because you always just replace your placeholder w' entirely with a part of the production. But as the given solution claims `bababa...` is a valid word in L, I presume the `|` between `ba` and `w'` is or should not be there.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I do agree that the solution doesn't make sense. That is why I was breaking my head over it, trying to understand why it would be that way. It is supposed to be a "recursively defined" Language

Comment: @SilverMs: Ok, if you consider this answer suitable, please click the green checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer.